# multidimensional rdf datacube and google refine

Tags: rdf, openrefine, data-cube

I am trying to convert some multidimensional databases (3 columns-dimensions, 1 column value) to RDF datacube using google refine. Because I have some problems with the modeling, is there any good example (or some ready RDFs with that structure) that I can look?

I have found some nice webpages (like LATC and others) but they miss the critical point of multidimensionality.

thanks
christos

Answer (score 0):

Please look at these tutorials about google refine and data cube

http://goo.gl/CDixE2

http://wifo5-03.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/latc/toollibrary/screencast.html